# Passive FTP not working properly

Tags: iptables, fedora, vsftpd

I've been having a problem with configuring vsftpd. I have managed to get active FTPS working fine, but passive is being stubborn. I think the problem is with how iptables is managing ports. When I try to use passive ftps on filezilla, everything connects, but the directory listing fails with `EHOSTUNREACH`. Here is the exchange between the client and the server setting up passive mode

```
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,10,169,39).
Command:    LIST
Error:      The data connection could not be established: EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host
```

Here is the relevant section of my `vsftpd.conf`:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

Here is the output of `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 21 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 20 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:safetynetp:50000 dpts:safetynetp:50000 ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Allow passive ftp inbound connections */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 21 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data ctstate ESTABLISHED /* Allow ftp connections on port 20 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:safetynetp:50000 dpts:safetynetp:50000 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED /* Allow passive ftp inbound connections */
```

Here is the command I used to set the output rule. The input one is very similar, but I can provide it if it is needed.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 40000:50000 --dport 40000:50000 -m conntrack -- ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow passive ftp inbound connections"
```

I can't find any info on the `safetynetp` part of the passive iptables rules online, and I think the problem is that this is conflicting with the range of ports (40,000-50,000) that I have set, as it looks like it is just accepting port 50,000.

The iptables may not be the problem at all, I don't know. If more info is needed I can certainly give it out.

EDIT:

Here is the client's iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Why not just use scp/sftp and completely avoid all of the active/passive nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

Is the FTP server you are connecting to on the other side of a NAT router? I see 192.168. in your IP there so there is a private network involved. You've got a pretty open iptables setup, so I don't think that's the issue (though you could try flushing the tables and seeing if that makes any difference).

Passive FTP requires the FTP server to make a new connection back to your FTP client ([see here for a more detailed description of passive FTP](http://www.rhyshaden.com/ftp.htm)), so this new return connection will more than likely fail to get back through a NAT router. There is an FTP module for IPTables which I think deals with this, but if NAT is involved, I'd just use active FTP (or as other comment says - use something else altogether if possible).

The IPTables you've shown is your for FTP client, not a router of some sort, correct?

Comment: the iptables is for the ftps server. I think I know what the problem is, from your answer. My client's firewall isn't allowing the new connection. Right? I have edited to include my client's iptables.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen issues that the ftp server is giving out a NAT address, when the public address of the FTP server is the one that should be configured.  This causes issues with the passive connection as the client is expecting a different address.  The initial connection normally works in that scenario, but passive mode doesn't work.

Take a look at your vsftpd configuration, or feel free to share it.